# Minimum version of Delphi to build Metropolis UI Apps?

Tags: delphi, windows-8

What is the minimum version of Delphi needed to build Metropolis UI apps for windows 8? Clearly the latest version has it...but what about earlier versions, when was this feature added?

I am trying to get a sense of how mature the support for this feature was in XE4, but my googlefu was failing me.

Comment: Delphi XE3? http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Developing_Metropolis_UI_Applications I answered too quickly and deleted my answer. I was sure that you could only develop these in Visual Studio, I was way wrong. I use XE2 and this is not available, and was under the impression that it would never be available.

Comment: I googled xe3 new features and sure enough, it's in the list: http://suretalent.blogspot.com/2012/09/embarcadero-delphi-xe3-new-features-of.html

Comment: @Jerry Metropolis UI is Embarcadero's fake WinRT/Metro/Modern UI feature. True WinRT is only possible with Visual Studio or another .net compiler.

Comment: @JerryDodge You'll have to wait 'cos it won't happen any time soon. Use VS and C#.

Comment: @Jerry No, that's not feasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Metropolis UI feature was [added in Delphi XE3](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/What%27s_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE3#New_Metropolis_UI_Applications_for_VCL_and_FireMonkey).